# Is there a completely "layout-neutral" HTML container element?

Tags: html, css

Sometimes I want to put a wrapper element around several other HTML elements *with the sole purpose* of setting up a convenient CSS selector to refer to all the contained elements:

```html
<TAG id="just-a-handy-wrapper">
    <abc ...>
        ...
    </abc>
    ...
    <pqr ...>
        ...
    </pqr>
</TAG>
```

...and in the CSS:

```css
#just-a-handy wrapper * {
    ...
}
```

I find this easier to manage and maintain than the alternative of assigning a common class to all the items captured by the `#just-a-handy wrapper *` selector above.

In this example, I've used fictitious tags `<abc>`, ..., `<pqr>`, etc., for the contained elements to stress the fact that I'm looking for a solution that works irrespective of the nature of the specific tags among the contents.

I've also used the fictitious tag `TAG` as a placeholder for the desired "wrapper tag", because my question is precisely about the best HTML tag to use for this purpose.  By "best" I mean most "universal" in the types of elements it can contain in valid HTML5, and "most layout-neutral".

IOW, the ideal HTML tag would the one where the page including the code above would always be rendered *exactly* the same as one where the `<tag ...>` and `</tag>` lines were removed, or commented out:

```html
<!-- <tag id="just-a-handy-wrapper"> -->
    <div ...>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
    <div ...>
        ...
    </div>
<!-- </tag> -->
```

A `div`, for example, is not "layout-neutral" (the browser will generally have strong ideas about how to layout a `div`), therefore it would not do to set `tag` equal to `div`.  Here's a simple example of this:

- [original](http://jsfiddle.net/0j2vtj46/)
- [with `<div>` wrapper around two of the three blue
  rectangles](http://jsfiddle.net/sr04wnmz/)

Comment: Since the children of your `<tag>` element are `<div>` (which are rendered as block-level elements by default), I don't see why wrapping them with `<div>` again will not be "layout-neutral". Being layout neutral or not depends on the default appearance the browser gives to the inner elements anyway.

Comment: @Terry: the fact that the children were divs was an inessential aspect of the question.  I have edited my post to stress this point.

Comment: @kjo there was no mention of block in the original question.

Comment: @Mousey: I don't follow your comment.

Comment: @kjo I answered based on the fact you may be wanting this for inline elements only, so having to edit my answer

Comment: @Mousey: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, there is a [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) for that supported by [major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents)

```
display: contents
```

E.g.
`<section class="container"><div>Parent is virtually not rendered</div></section>`

```
.container {
   display: contents;
}
```

Comment: This will sure be nice.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, I fear there is no such tag.

Imaginge a scenario where your `<abc>` or `<pqr>` tags are block-level tags, say `<p>` tags. In order to fullfill your requirement (the layout should be the same, if the tag is there or not), the container tag would need to be a blocklevel tag to be w3c conform, and it should not have any default stylings. As far as I know, a `<div>` is exaclty that.

Now imaginge a scenario where your`<abc>` or `<pqr>` are inline tags like `<i>` or `<b>`. In order to fullfill your requirement the container tag would need to be a inline tag itself, otherwise it would break the line.

Now the thing is it is not possible for a tag to be inline- and block-level at the same time.

And to answer your question about the most universal tags:
Use `div` as a container for block-level contents and use `span` as a container for inline contents. These tags are made for this purpose.

Comment: In fact, the div element is defined to be a generic container.

Comment: I agree that it would be trivial to support such a tag, but as it is with html/css, each tag has a display property. Thus in this world it is a cosmic impossibillity

Answer (score 4):

From the [w3c Visual Formatting Model document](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow):

> Boxes in the normal flow belong to a formatting context, which may be `block` or `inline`, but not both simultaneously

In your fiddles, the lack of layout neutrality is demonstrated by the `text-align: center;` rule on the `.outer` element no longer applying to the `.inner` elements, once there was a wrapper element layered between them.

I know that you'd prefer to speak in generalities to stress your point about a layout neutral tag, but since all HTML elements *must have a formatting context*, there will always be a side-effect to adding more tags to the markup. (In this case, your `<div>` tag is a `block`.)

Most often there's no visual issue, but insofar as your layout depends on formatting contexts, adding more elements will always run counter to you having a layout-neutral tag.

I would echo @Mario A's answer that where you need to wrap a tag with something layout neutral, wrap `block` tags with `<div>`s, and `inline` tags, with `spans`, so as not to introduce new formatting contexts that could disrupt your layout.

Answer (score 3):

`<span>` is layout neutral but it depends on which types of elements go within in, for example it cannot contain block elements like `<div>`. Whether an element renders as a block depends on the element, but can be specifying, for example `<div style="display:inline-block">` or `<div style="display:table-cell">` display differently.

Since it's a CSS question, you can use IDs on your elements to add extra CSS rules, or apply several different classes to one ID. EG

```
<div id="mydiv" class="blacktext">helloo</div>
<div class="blacktext class2">hello</div> <!-- apply class blacktext and class2-->
```

CSS

.class2 { background-color: #FF0000;}

**References**

[1] [the `<span>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)

- The  tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.
- The  tag provides no visual change by itself.
- The  tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a part of a document.

[2] [span vs div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1611172/4258817)

Answer on stackoverflow about `inline-block`, `block` and `inline` with `<span>` and ` compared

Answer (score 3):

There isn't such a tag, and there very well should be one.

Some tags like `fieldset` have behavior that affect child elements, but also do not require having any rendering. `fieldset`, when disabled, will disable all children input elements and is incredibly useful. However, you cannot wrap it around a `<tr>` specifically because it needs to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [slot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot) tag can be a good candidate for your requirements.